# MySQL Query with LEFT JOIN, SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried `CREATE VIEW` in MySQL but I do not get what I need.

I have two tables, `servicios`:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+
| id_servicos | fecha      | cantidad |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| 1           | 2016-05-02 | 2        |
| 2           | 2016-05-03 | 3        |
| 3           | 2016-05-03 | 5        |
+-------------+------------+----------+
```

and `actuacion`:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------+
| id_actuacion | clv_servicio | grupo  |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
| 1            | 1            | RED    |
| 2            | 1            | RED    |
| 3            | 2            | BLUE   |
| 4            | 4            | ORANGE |
| 5            | 3            | RED    |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

and I want the output to look similar to this:

```
RED, 7
BLUE, 2
ORANGE, 4
```

So my query is looking like this

```
SELECT actuacion.grupo,
       SUM(servicios.cantidad) AS total
FROM (actuacion
JOIN servicios ON actuacion.clv_servicio = servicios.id_servicos)
GROUP BY actuacion.grupo
```

and the result is

```
RED, 9
BLUE, 2
ORANGE, 4
```

I think you have to match before dates(fecha) to then the sum of the quantities(cantidad) and so do not add twice the RED group
I need the result of RED is 7

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to better explain why result of RED is 7. What do you sum?

Comment: So, based on the data provided, it seems that your problem is duplicated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the unique combinations in the `actuacion` table in a query used as a derived table and join with that.

This should give you the result you want:

```
Select t.grupo,
       Sum(servicios.cantidad) As total
From (select distinct clv_servicio, grupo from actuacion) as t
Join servicios On t.clv_servicio = servicios.id_servicos
Group By t.grupo
```

Comment: Works perfectly, it is what I wanted. thank you very much.

Comment: Because when I think this query gives me this error:  #HY000View's SELECT contains subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: @Jose Oh ok. I forgot that MySQL has that particular restriction on views. One solution would be to create a separate view for the subquery and join with that in the main view instead. This might not give good performance though as you won't be able to use indexes if I recall right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sub-query and use `GROUP BY` in following:

```
SELECT grupo,
       SUM(s.cantidad) total
FROM (SELECT clv_servicio, 
             grupo 
      FROM actuacion a 
      GROUP BY clv_servicio, grupo
      ) x 
JOIN servicios s ON x.clv_servicio = s.id_servicos
GROUP BY grupo
```